# Html how to make a table with multiple headers?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html-table

I want to make a table. I know how to make in html simple table. I want to have a few headers. A few types of header, similar to photo. I don't know number of it, I would count it in my program. What should I use, about what should I read?

I tried this:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
    <th>AAA1</th>
    <th>AAA2</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>KKK1</th>
    <th>KKK2</th>
    <th>KKK3</th>
    <th>KKK3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>PPP1</th>
    <th>PPP2</th>
    <th>PPP3</th>
    <th>PPP4</th>
    <th>PPP5</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

But I know it is too simple and will not give me something similar to picture. I read about colspan, but it will not give me a result which I want.
Maybe there is a bootstrap for it?

[image]

Comment: *What should I use, about what should I read?* Learn JavaScript since you are obviously describing a need to dynamically change the structure of a table according to unknown requirements.

Comment: I prefer to avoid JavaScript, because I have never used it. I will have defined in my database amount of each group.  Maybe something with css. But what? Maybe I could try display one table on another?

Comment: CSS is very limited, and in order to even get close to what you need would be impossible with just HTML and CSS  AFAIK. Fundamentally I would assume that you'll need to use variables a few expressions and a way to manipulate what is rendered in a browser. CSS lacks variables and expressions that can be applied to leverage dynamic functions of such complex tasks. CSS and HTML are not languages.

Comment: Beyond the simple table markup in your question and what you have mentioned, you should learn about `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot`, the `col` tag, the `scope` attribute: `scope="row"` `=col` `=rowgroup` and `=colgroup`, the `headers` attribute etc.  These are all covered in the [Tables Tutorial](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/) that @cthrall mentioned in his answer, and linked to _one_ of the pages.  HTML tables and their CSS are incredibly flexible these days and can create pretty complex stuff.

Answer (score 5):

You can have different headers for different rows. There is a [good example on the W3 site](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/). If you have questions about markup validity, you can use [the W3 validator web page](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) to check your HTML.

Comment: I saw this page and I wrote that: "colspan" will not do work for me. Look on the picture, this third row: "L1, L2, L3...". Each of this group(Cw, Ps, L) have  separate color for data and own lines. If I would know that for example 'Ps' group would be half of 'Cw' I would use colspan. But I don't know. Cw could be 10, but L for example 17

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue in a complex situation involving some twig loops, etc ... and needed a better solution than what the other answers provided.

And this worked like charm:

```html
<!-- Some BootStrap -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Table --->
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <col/>
  <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
  <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Mars</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Venus</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Produced</th>
    <th scope="col">Sold</th>
    <th scope="col">Produced</th>
    <th scope="col">Sold</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Teddy Bears</th>
    <td>50,000</td>
    <td>30,000</td>
    <td>100,000</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Board Games</th>
    <td>10,000</td>
    <td>5,000</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Explanation of why this works, in detail, is [here](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/), and the docs of `<col/>` are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have some headers for a header you can use colspan attrebute for example if you want have 2 header for a header you can use colspan="2" for first header 
i wish i understood your mean.

also for tables ,, not for this problem you can use class="table" from bootstrap.

Comment: Bootstrap in itself has nothing to do with table markup. It just adds a style on top of a table, alongside with a few utilities maybe. 'use .table class from bootstrap' is far away from a real answer for OP.